# How to execute iframe function from flutter web's HtmlElementView

Tags: flutter, iframe, flutter-web

I used the iframeElement on HtmlElementView, and there is the bug on iframeElement that flutter button can't fire event on Stack widget, so I wrapper it into div element.

```
class _BroadcastViewState extends State<BroadcastView> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final IFrameElement iframeElement = IFrameElement();
    iframeElement.height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString();
    iframeElement.width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString();
    iframeElement.src =
        '/assets/index.html';
    iframeElement.style.border = 'none';
    iframeElement.id = 'iframe';
    final wrapper = DivElement()
      ..style.width = '100%'
      ..style.height = '100%';
    wrapper.append(iframeElement);
    // ignore:undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      BroadcastView.createViewId,
      (int viewId) => wrapper,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HtmlElementView(
      viewType: BroadcastView.createViewId,
    );
  }
}
```

And I used the Stack widget to add button, and to trigger the iframe's method

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';

class BroadcastScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          BroadcastView(),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: RawMaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  IFrameElement frame = querySelector('#iframe');
                  var jsFrame = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(frame);
                  JsObject jsDocument = jsFrame['contentDocument'];
                  jsDocument.callMethod('join');
                },
                child: new Icon(
                  Icons.live_tv,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 25.0,
                ),
                shape: new CircleBorder(),
                elevation: 2.0,
                fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, querySelector('#iframe') always return null, even I tried the query at Chrome console, still return null.
How to access iframe element and function from flutter's HtmlElementView?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I found the way can access the iframe

```dart
document.querySelector('flt-platform-view').shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe')
```

Comment: Yeah, but even if I can get ahold of the J's context, I'm seeing an error where calling the method throws an unhelpful "Source maps aren't finished building" stack trace error despite being able to call the method from Chrome console. Flutter Web is a nightmare.

Comment: And whats next? How do you use that?